# Unicode Regex in Python 3 (from Python 2 Code)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x

I'm trying to convert my Python 2 script to Python 3. How do we do Regex with Unicode?

This is what I had in Python 2 which works It replaces quotes to « and »:

`text = re.sub(ur'"(.*?)"', ur'«\1»', text)`

I have some really complex ones which the "ur" made it so easy. But it doesn't work in Python 3:

`text = re.sub(ur'ه\sایم([\]\.،\:»\)\s])', ur'ه\u200cایم\1', text)`

Comment: You do not need `u` in Python 3 as all strings are Unicode by default. Omit the `u` prefixes.

Comment: @Klaus D. IMO not a duplicate. Referenced question is for python 2.x

Comment: Thanks. Removing `u` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All strings in Python3 are unicode by default. Just remove the `u` and you should be fine.

In Python2 strings are lists of bytes by default, so we use `u` to mark them as unicode strings.

Comment: What about if you're writing code that is supposed to work in both Python 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

> Since Python 3.0, the language features a str type that contain
>   Unicode characters, meaning any string created using "unicode rocks!",
>   'unicode rocks!', or the triple-quoted string syntax is stored as
>   Unicode.

[Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) This doc will help you.

so, you just do want every you do in Python2, and it will works, no extra effects.